# Make javascript code more efficient avoid creating more lines

Tags: javascript, coding-efficiency

I have this in JS... What is better for make code efficient?

```js
var hello = parseInt(document.getElementById("hello").value);
var hello2 = hello * 0.02;
var hello1 = parseFloat(hello2);
var hello3 = Math.round(hello1 * 100) / 100;
if (hello3 > 3.11) {
  hello3 = 2.11;
}
```

Comment: Add all the code. Where are "anti" and "anti2" variables?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "creating more lines."  It's unclear to me that any part of this code deals with lines.

Comment: @aepifano They're supposed to say `hello`. If you look at the edit history, it was @DarrenSweeney who changed them to `anti` by mistake.

Comment: @Run_Script Wow! I have absolutely no clue how that happened - wasn't intentional - I copied it into a snippet, hit tidy then copied it back into the post, weird - Apologies all

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I think the OP corrected this themselves at some point, and you'd probably started the edit before having loaded the correction and thus unknowingly changed it back to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Make javascript code more efficient

The only thing I can imagine you're asking to increase the efficiency is achieving the same thing with fewer variables.

This code uses just one, `hello3`:

```js
var hello3 = Math.round(parseFloat(parseInt(document.getElementById("hello").value)*0.02)*100)/100;

if (hello3 > 3.11) {
  hello3 = 2.11;
}
```

> avoid creating more lines

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by this. In theory everything could be on one line and the code would still work:

```js
var hello3 = Math.round(parseFloat(parseInt(document.getElementById("hello").value)*0.02)*100)/100; if (hello3 > 3.11) {hello3 = 2.11;}
```

But I don't see the point of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

`var hello1= parseFloat(hello2);` is not necessary because `hello2` is already a float.

It's not clear which of the variables you need at the end of the calculation but assuming it's just `hello3` then:

`hello3 = ( ( ( hello3 = Math.round( parseInt(document.getElementById("hello").value) * 0.02 ) / 100 ) > 3.11 ) ? 2.11 : hello3 )`

This is really difficult to read, though so I would format it like this:

```
hello3 = (
    ( ( hello3 = Math.round( parseInt(document.getElementById("hello").value) * 0.02 ) / 100 ) > 3.11 )
        ?
    2.11
        :
    hello3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save all in only one variable (without breaking the indentation).
I think you no need all those variables initializations but all in one line it's too much, for me.

```
var hello1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("hello").value) * 0.02;
hello1 = Math.round(hello1 * 100) / 100;
if (hello1 > 3.11) {
  hello1 = 2.11;
}
```

A working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-code-efficiency?file=index.js